# Geometrical interpretation of points of orders 2,3 and 4 on elliptical curve over field of real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let us have elliptical curve $E$ over $\mathbb{R}$ in standard (Weierstrass) form $y^2 = x^2 + ax + b$. What is a geometrical meaning of points of order 2, 3 and 4?

I was able to solve task for points of order 2. Definition says that order $n$ of point $P$ is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $nP = O$. Then for order 2: $2P = P \oplus P = O$. Operation $\oplus$ is standard addition over elliptic curves. I could say $P \oplus P = O \rightarrow P = -P$. Lets say $P = (x,y)$, then we looking for points that $(x,y) = (x,-y)$ then the solution is $\{(x,y)\in E |y=-y \}$ .. well, only number $y=-y$ is $0$, so my interpretation of this result is that *points of order 2 lays on x-axis* $(y=0)$.

With orders 3 and 4 I am stuck. I could find some relations but I am not able to interpret that results geometrically. Results should be: order 3 - inflection points and order 4 - intersection of tangent of point order 4 and $E$ lays on x-axis.

Comment: I believe order 3 is explained in "Rational points on elliptic curves", in the chapter on torsion points.

Comment: This is close to being a FAQ (on elliptic curves). Remember that $2P$ is the mirror image of the third point of intersection of $E$ and the tangent drawn at $P$. If $3P=O$, then $2P=-P$. And the mirror image of $-P$ is of course $P$, so the tangent at $P$ should make a triple contact. If $4P=O$ then $2(2P)=0$, so $2P$ should have order two, when $2P$ should be on the $x$-axis (and its own mirror).

Comment: Yes I could see a few questions like this, but I am not able to assemble or find a real proof..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank dr. Lahtonen. For the sake of completeness I answer my question with his idea.

Let's say we have $3P = O$, then we want to find a point that $2P = -P$. It means we are looking for a point which tangent intersects elliptic curve $E$ exactly in the point P. Only points which satisfies this are points of inflection.

If we have $4P = O$ it means that $2(2P)=O$. It means we are looking for points which tangent intersects curve in the point of where $2P=O$ which solution is in the question.